# Create Sub menu through Clickonce

Tags: .net, clickonce, publish

It's known that clickonce creates an entry point of the application in `Start->Programs->PublisherName->ProductName`. But is it possible to create a sub-menu after the `PublisherName`? For example, I have two clickonce applications which currently shows up in the Start->Programs like this:

```
Start->Programs->XYZ->Application.exe // This is a trial version of the app
Start->Programs->XYZ Corporation->Application.exe // This is the full version of the app
```

I need to change this into:

```
Start->Programs->XYZ Corporation->TrialVersion->Application.exe
                                |
                                ->FullVersion->Application.exe
```

I can't get a screenshot of what I meant. I hope my question is clear. Is this possible in clickonce?

**EDIT**

Just came to know about another clickonce application [Blu](http://2010.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/blu/) which can be downloaded from [here](http://blu.en.softonic.com/). This application creates a sub menu after the `PublisherName`.

Comment: Don't think it's possible. http://www.windowsdevelop.com/clickonce-setup--deployment-projects/start-menu-location-for-clickonce-application-4669.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS2010 or VS2012, you can specify a Suite Name in addition to Publisher and Product Name. The Suite Name will appear on the start menu between the publisher (the top menu entry under Start) and the product name.

For example, if you set Company Name to "MyCompany", SuiteName to "MySuite", and product name to "MyProduct", you will see MyCompany under start menu, MySuite under the MyCompany folder, and MyProduct under the MySuite folder.

Comment: I don't think so. You need to set it in the project properties before publishing the application and signing it.